# error with using 'finalize, catcherror' operators

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to implement an angular data table using the great example provided by angular university. But i'm stuck on implementing my datasource. Here is my datasource:

```
import { Aircraft } from '../shared/aircraft';
import { AircraftInfoService } from './aircraft-info.service';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { CollectionViewer, DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catchError';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/finalize';

export class allAircraftInfoDataSource implements DataSource<Aircraft> {

  private aircraftDBSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Aircraft[]>([]);
  private loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  public loading$ = this.loadingSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private aircraftInfoService: AircraftInfoService) {}

  connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Aircraft[]> {
      return this.aircraftDBSubject.asObservable();
  }

  disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
      this.aircraftDBSubject.complete();
      this.loadingSubject.complete();
  }

  getAircraft() {

      this.loadingSubject.next(true);

      this.aircraftInfoService.getAircraft().pipe(
        catchError(() => **of**([])),
        finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false))
    )
    .subscribe(data => this.aircraftDBSubject.next(data));      
  }    
}
```

I'm gettings errors on 'catchError', 'of', 'finalize' and the second use of 'data' is generating errors. Here are my compile errors:

```
ERROR in ../../src/app/services/aircraft-info-datasource.service.ts(31,9): error TS2552: Cannot find name 'catchError'. Did you mean 'RTCError'?
../../src/app/services/aircraft-info-datasource.service.ts(31,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'of'.
../../src/app/services/aircraft-info-datasource.service.ts(32,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'finalize'.
../../src/app/services/aircraft-info-datasource.service.ts(34,52): error TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Aircraft[]'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Aircraft[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
```

I thought I'd followed the examples to the letter, but I'm obviously missing something. What do i need to correct?

thanks.....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're importing RxJS 5 "patch style" of operators and trying to use them as RxJS 6 "pipable operators" (also `catchError` was formerly known as `catch` in RxJS 5).

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

For migration docs see:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Answer (score 1):

You need to Import the `catchError` symbol from `rxjs/operators`:

```
import { catchError, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53818595/9386929) for some details on the new changes that came with rxjs from v6+.